# How to get unique key in pandas dataframe without hardcode the variable

Tags: python, pandas

Here my `Dataset_A`

```
Unique_Key     Column_A     Column_B    Column_C    ...    Column X
```

And my `df`

```
Columns     Table
Columns_C     Dataset_A
Columns_G     Dataset_B
```

Here's what I do

```
a = df[df['Table'] == 'Table_A']
acols = a['Column'].tolist()
Dataset_A = pd.read_csv("Selected_Agreement.csv")
Dataset_A[acols]
```

FYI `Dataset_A`, `Dataset_B`, ..., `Dataset_G` has same `Unique_Key`. When I want to merge selected column for machine learning purpose the `Unique_Key` is not selected. How to get `Unique_Key' in pandas dataframe without hardcode the variable, so in other words, instead of

```
[In]  acols
[Out] ['Column_A', 'Column_F', 'Column_H']
```

I need

```
[In]  acols
[Out] ['Unique_Key','Column_A', 'Column_F', 'Column_H']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in `df` is no information about `Unique_Key`is necessary add it by one element list like:

```
acols = ['Unique_Key'] + a['Column'].tolist()
```